# Is it possible to get some useful information from pinging a web site?

Tags: sql, security, ubuntu, ping

I have found a website which is just pinging other web pages, there is an input for entering a website's address, and its output the result to the screen as a paragraph, and I have mentioned that this input does not validate, so I tried to ping itself like, address of the current website; and id (site; id) and the output was

```
uid=1000(ubuntu) gid=1000(ubuntu) groups=1000(ubuntu),27(sudo),1001(rvm)
```

But I do not know what does it mean, and maybe there are more useful things, to receive any data from the web page and is it possible to make SQL injections for such inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think this is sql injection. 
 I believe you have stumbled across `remote code execution`, which is even better then `sql injection` ;) (the output that you see is a result of `id` command in `bash`) 
 since the output indicates that it is a ubuntu server. you can try some linux commands and gather more info on the server.

Note: Exploiting these vulnerabilities is mostly illegal. Unless the website admin / maintainer allows it.

And to answer your question. it is definitely possible to gather more info on the same website if you have `remote code execution` (if you have `rce` you can do pretty much anything). or if you want to gather info on other websites. i would suggest doing some basic information gathering like whois and so on..

Answer (score 0):

- The output you have posted is not output from ping.
- The web service that serves web pages and the network service that responds to pings are completely different things. I.e., you can ping a server that doesn't host any web pages -- it's simply an indication that the server is up and connected to the network.
- Ping is often used as a sort of poor-man's uptime monitor. It can also be useful for determining if there's any network latency between the two machines.
- Ping can not be used to perform SQL injections or any other sort of web based attack, as it doesn't use the web. It can be used to perform a crude DoS attack by flooding the machine with an enormous amount of ping requests.
- Machine administrators often disable ping responses, so the inability to ping a machine doesn't mean it's down.